# GAE/Go: datastore iterator too slow

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Iteration to datastore query result in GAE/Go is very slow.

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("MyStruct")
gaeLog.Infof(ctx, "run")                                                 // (1)
it := client.Run(ctx, q)
list := make([]MyStruct, 0, 10000)
gaeLog.Infof(ctx, "start mapping")                                       // (2)
for {
    var m MyStruct
    _, err := it.Next(&m)
    if err == iterator.Done {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        gaeLog.Errorf(ctx, "datastore read error : %s ", err.Error())
        <some error handling>
        break
    }
    list = append(list , m)
}
gaeLog.Infof(ctx, "end mapping. count : %d", len(list))                  // (3)
```

The result is below.

```
18:02:11.283 run                             // (1)
18:02:11.291 start mapping                   // (2)
18:02:15.741 end mapping. count : 2400       // (3)
```

It takes about 4.5 seconds between `(2)` and `(3)`, just only 2400 record. It is very slow.

How can I improve performance?

**[Update]**

I added the query in above code `q := datastore.NewQuery("MyStruct")`.
I tried to retrieve all the entities in the kind `MyStruct`.  This kind has 2400 entities.

Comment: It's hard to answer the question as-is. The speed of a database query is going to depend on what indexes the database has and the specifics of the query. None of those details appears in the question.

Comment: @PaulHankin where takes time is between (2) and (3), that is after client.Run has completed.

Comment: I think you're saying that the 4.5s can't be the database because you think `client.Run` does all the lookups in the database in one go. That's probably wrong -- depending on your indexes and query, `it.Next()` may perform more database lookups.

Comment: @PaulHankin I see, I certainly thought all the lookups will be completed by  `client.Run`. I have updated my post, added the query detail  and the datastore kind.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that you should probably change your list to `[]*MyStruct` and also make `var m *MyStruct`. I believe `append` is copying your struct because you are passing it by value.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear I changed my code  `list := make([]*MyStruct, 0, 10000)`  and `list = append(list , &m)`, but this could not improve performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `cloud.google.com/go/datastore` and found it is slow. I migrated to use `google.golang.org/appengine/datastore`.

The result is as follows, less than 1 second.

```
13:57:46.216 run
13:57:46.367 start mapping
13:57:47.063 end mapping. count : 2400
```